# IBM jsonstore is storing an object on ascending order of key

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, jsonstore

My requirement is to store an object in JSONStore  as it is but it seems JSONstore is storing the object in ascending order of key.

### For Example:

```
    If my object is {name:'myName',age:23} and I am storing it in JSONstore.
    While trying to retrieve this object from JSONstore  ,I am getting as 
   {age:23,name:'myName'}
```

My objective is to get {name:'myName',age:23}

Why JSONstore is storing like that ? Is there any method to prevent this by using any optional parameter .